# Problem of install fuerte on Mac

Tags: catkin, macos, ros-fuerte, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to run Cmake with:

> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/fuerte -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF

it shows a error

> -- +++ catkin
> -- Could NOT find PY_em (missing:  PY_EM)
> CMake Error at catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:29 (message):
> Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
> installing package 'python-empy'
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> catkin/cmake/all.cmake:52 (include)
> catkin/CMakeLists.txt:12 (include)
> Anyone can help me to fix it?
> I am using Mac OS X 10.7.3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32544/problem-of-install-fuerte-on-mac/) by [Haojun Guan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2244/haojun-guan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haojun Guan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2244/haojun-guan/) on 2012-04-25**:
I am sure that i follow the instructions well, and i have install the empy package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try these [instuctions](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source), I think they are more up to date. I followed them and have gotten pretty far in the installation.  Make sure your python path is correct too.

I am getting stuck with PCL (compiling pcl_ros actually). I have also forked rosdistro and am trying to get the homebrew stuff working correctly for pcl, openni, and ps-engine ... but still having issues.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at the error message in detail:
... **Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'... try installing package 'python-empy'**  ...

Did you follow the [installation instructions](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew)?

You should also be able to run "pip install empy".

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across this error when trying to install Groovy on osx 10.7.5 (lion).
It turns out python 2.6 was being used instead of 2.7.
So i ran:

> cmake ..
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2.7 -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF

instead. Note the -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE .

---

Originally posted by [ians](https://answers.ros.org/users/4027/ians/) with karma: 31 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3